# Swiper destroy - cleanStyle not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swiper.js

I have the following very simple slider that needs to be initialised on mobile only:

```
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    let init = false;
    let swiper = jQuery('.swiper');
    if (swiper) {
        function swiperCard() {
            if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                if (!init) {
                    init = true;
                    swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
                        slidesPerView: 1.2,
                        modules: [Scrollbar],
                        scrollbar: {
                            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
                            draggable: true,
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else if (init) {
                swiper.destroy();
                init = false;
            }
        }
        swiperCard();
        window.addEventListener('resize', swiperCard);
    }
 });
```

**The slider correctly stops being initialised above 768px but the CSS remains active.** I've tried using swiper.destroy(deleteInstance, cleanStyles) instead of swiper.destroy() but it doesn't work (the slider even stays initialised).

What I am missing? Thanks